# Comparar duas strings simples em C, entrada com scanf();

Tags: c, string

o que pretendo fazer é bem simples. eu faço o programa pedir por uma senha, o programa compara, e se a senha for válida, o programa prossegue.

Um exemplo:

```
char pass[5];

printf("insira a senha: ");

while(pass!="asdfg") { //enquanto a senha for diferente/inválida
    scanf("%s",&pass); //entrada da senha
};
```

Quando tento executar esse código, o programa simplesmente não aceita a senha `asdfg` e continua pedindo a senha.

Comment: Neste seu pequeno pedaço de código, o erro não está apenas na comparação, mas em outros lugares também. Pena que não tem como mostrar, já que a pergunta foi fechada.

Answer (score 0):

Quando for pegar uma string não precisa utilizar o **&**, J que o nome da string já é um endereço de memória.

```
char pass[5];

printf("insira a senha: ");

while(!strcmp(pass,"asdfg")) { //enquanto a senha for diferente/inválida
    scanf("%s", pass); //entrada da senha
};
```

Comment: O problema é mais amplo do que isso

Comment: @Amadeus porque?

Comment: Percebi fiz a alteração, obrigado @Amadeus

Comment: Em C, não se compara strings com `!=`. Outro problema, `scanf` é propenso a _buffer overflow_  e finalmente, `%s` não captura palavras com espaço